# How to find sufficient complete statistic for the density $f(x\mid\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}\exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)})$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

For the pdf $$f(x\mid\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}\exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)})\,,\qquad-\infty<x<\infty,-\infty<\theta<\infty$$, let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d observations. How to find the sufficient statistic and show the complete statistic does not exit?

The answer of it is that the order statistics are minimal sufficient statistics. I want to know under what circumstances we should consider order statistics?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. If it is, you should add a "self study" tag.

Comment: The premises of your question are not correct. The order statistics are not minimal sufficient and a very simple complete sufficient statistic does exist. Just apply the transformations $y=\exp(-x)$ and $\mu=\exp(\theta)$ and this will become clear.

Answer (score 4):

*Answer already hinted at in comments...*

A complete sufficient statistic *does exist* for this family of distributions, a [Gumbel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with scale parameter unity. The set of order statistics is *not* minimal sufficient here. We should consider order statistics, which are trivially sufficient for any family of distributions, when we cannot find any other (non-trivial) sufficient statistic, say for the Laplace distribution and the Cauchy distribution with unknown location parameter.

Due to independence, joint density of $(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ is

\begin{align}
f_{\theta}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)&=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i\mid\theta)
\\&=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+n\theta}\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-(x_i-\theta)}\right)
\\&=\exp\left(-e^{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-x_i}+n\theta\right)e^{-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}
\\&=g(\theta,t(\mathbf x))\,h(\mathbf x)\qquad,\text{ for all } \mathbf x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\,,\,\theta\in\mathbb R
\end{align}

where $g(\theta,t(\mathbf x))=\exp\left(-e^{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-x_i}+n\theta\right)$ depends on $\theta$ and on $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ through $t(\mathbf x)=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-x_i}$ and $h(\mathbf x)=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ is independent of $\theta$.

So by *Factorisation theorem*, a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $$T(\mathbf X)=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-X_i}$$

---

Let $Y=e^{-X}$ where $X$ has the density $f(x\mid\theta)$.

Then density of $Y$ is

\begin{align}f_Y(y)&=f(-\ln y\mid\theta)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|\mathbf1_{y>0}
\\&=\frac{1}{y}e^{\ln y+\theta}\exp\left(-e^{\ln y+\theta}\right)\mathbf1_{y>0}
\\&=e^{\theta}\exp(-ye^{\theta})\mathbf1_{y>0}
\end{align}

That is, $Y\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda=e^{\theta}(>0)$.

In other words, $e^{-X_i}\stackrel{\text{i.i.d}}\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for each $i=1,2,\cdots,n$, which implies

$$T\sim\text{Gamma}(\lambda,n)$$

---

To show that $T$ is indeed a complete statistic, we have to show that for any function $\psi$ of $T$, $$E_{\theta}(\psi(T))=0\implies \psi(T)=0\quad,\text{ a.e.}$$

Now, 
\begin{align}E_{\theta}(\psi(T))&=0
\\\implies \int_0^\infty \psi(t)e^{-\lambda t}t^{n-1}\,dt  &=0
\end{align}

It [can be shown](https://books.google.com/books?id=IeNHAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA242&ots=6QKnsSEoe4&dq=unicity%20property%20of%20mellin%20transform&pg=PA242#v=onepage&q&f=false) using the unicity property of Mellin transform that the last implication means $\psi(t)$ itself is identically zero. There might be an easier proof for completeness but I could not find one.

Comment: Since the pdf is a member of the one-parameter exponential family, it can be directly stated that $\sum e^{-X_i}$ is a complete sufficient statistic.