# Does this distribution belong to the exponential family?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, complete-statistics, ancillary-statistics

I was looking at a problem in the book of "Statistical Inference" second edition by George Casella and Roger L. Berger from chapter 6 that deals with sufficient statistics, minimal sufficient statistics, complete statistics, etc.

In problem 6.20 part d) I have the following question

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n$ be iid observations with the following pdf:

$f(x|\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}\cdot exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)})$

Where $-\infty <x< \infty$ and $-\infty <\theta< \infty$

Find a complete sufficient statistic or show that one does not exist.

I proved that this belongs to the exponential family rewriting the pdf the following way:
$f(x|\theta)=e^{-x}e^{\theta}\cdot exp(-e^{-x}\cdot e^{\theta})$

$h(x)=e^{-x}$;
$c(\theta)=e^{\theta}$;
$w(\theta)=e^{\theta}$;
$t(x)=-e^{-x}$

so I concluded that it has a complete sufficient statistic due to the theorem:

[image]

However, I then looked at a solution manual and they suggested a different answer so I'm kind of confused and don't know what I did wrong.

This was the solution:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The solution is non-sensical if indeed the support of the density is the entire real line. The sufficient statistic is then the sum of the $\exp\{X_i\}$'s. Imho, the [solution manual](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams570/Solutions-Casella-Berger.pdf) does not correspond to the same edition and hence 6.20 is not the same problem in different editions.

Comment: You are looking at the Gumbel distribution. Related question is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276391

Comment: I checked both the second edition and the solution manual for that edition and there is clearly a mistake in the answer. Maybe the person who wrote the answer got confused with the location-scale Gumbel, which stands outside the exponential families...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was starting to wonder if I was not worthy of living anymore haha. Now that I have verified that this distribution indeed belongs to the exponential family I won't be depriving myself of any more sleep. Thanks again.